# Ajax event only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

when i enter the wrong details and run it. it pops up with the error message, but if i then enter the correct details and click run it again. the sign in button changes to "Connecting..." as it should but then nothing else happens

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var width = ( $(".main").width() - 5);
    if (width < 300) {
        $(".logo-img").css({"width":width});
    };

    $("#error").hide();

    $(function() {
        $('#login').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var token = $('#token').val();
            var username = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            var remember = $('#remember:checked').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'core/functions/ajaxLogin.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: { 'username' : username,
                        'password' : password, 
                        'remember' : remember, 
                        'token' : token },
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() { $('#login').val('Connecting...') },
                success: function( data ) {
                    if (data == 'success') {
                        setTimeout( "window.location.href='backorderbook';", 500 );
                    } else if( data == 'userorpass' ) {
                        $('#error').fadeIn();
                        $('#error_message')
                           .html('username or password were entered incorrectly');
                        $('#error').delay(3500).fadeOut();
                        $('#login').val('Sign In');
                    };
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: And what is your question? What have you done to debug your code?

Answer (score 1):

Reason behind working once.

when your ajax fired, first thing to do is show connecting.. then when you get response which is `data` your statement says

```
if data == success //redirects

elseif data == userpass //show you have invalid username/password and clear html
```

So what if your data is not succes / userpass

it will just run your ajax `beforeSend()` and not will remove connecting that seems to you running once.

I recommend that your data should be an object and check if there's an error with the message on it , in short have it on your backend and just jquery show that message

Answer (score 0):

There is a token generated when the login page is loaded and sent with the Ajax. But my PHP token system doesn't like the same token being sent over and over and blocks the request.

Answer (score -2):

run your function with Fiddler .. and/or add the error parameter to your ajax... odds are your web request isn't a success.